# VS 2012/2013 and .NET 4.5 Query

Tags: c#, .net

I am planning to install VS 2012 or 2013 and I was wondering if .NET 4.5 will get installed with it? I think it will but then what will happen to all my apps with target platform 4.0?

So my question is when I install VS, will my old apps which have target platform 4 contain elements of .NET 4.5?

Let say as example type string in 4.5 it has some improvements or something which 4.0 doesnt have. Will I get them even though I build against 4.0 according to target platform?

I would like to avoid some strange behavior in already existing projects just because I am running now visual studio 2013.

Any experience on this one guys?

Sorry in case of a duplicate question

Comment: Please use the full year names for the products, not an attempt to abbreviate them. You risk confusion because the *internal* version of VS 2012 is 11, and the *internal* version of VS2013 is 12, and, presumably, when they're next ready to offer CTPs or Betas or VS vNext, they'll almost certainly use the internal code, so it will, at that time, be VS 13 beta. And your question *isn't*, I presume, talking about VS13, since there's no public version of that available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you target .NET 4.0, your code will not be able to access types which are specific to .NET 4.5 or .NET 4.5.1. However, your code will be *running* against .NET 4.5. That is only a problem if you do not test against .NET 4.0. In that case, you could find that bugs are fixed in .NET 4.5, but your users may still be using .NET 4.0, which may still have the bugs.

Comment: To sum up I ll run with target 4.0 but in the background it will be 4.5 since I have 4.5 installed on my pc because of vs. However client has 4.0 and so he might get the bugs I couldn't fix since those bugs are already fixed in 4.5 and so to me no exception was thrown however the client might get errors. Do I get you right?

Comment: @devhedgehog: Yes, you are right. Just like the .NET framework version might (slightly) differ between Windows versions / bit versions.

Comment: @devhedgehog: that is exactly correct, but then, you should always test in the environment your users will be using - in this case, if you support .NET 4.0, then you should _test_ in .NET 4.0. The only problem would be if 1) There is a bug in .NET 4.0, which 2) your code can exercise, and 3) You don't test against .NET 4.0, so you don't _see_ the bug, and 4) The bug is fixed in .NET 4.5. If not all of these conditions are met, then there is no problem. Microsoft seems to be gambling that these conditions will only rarely occur together.

Comment: So technically.. testers should have 4.0 pcs since clients get 4.0 and developers could work on 4.5 with visual studio 2013. Right?

Comment: No. If your clients use .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5, then testers need to test in all three environments.

Comment: Your confusing me now. Testers should not get installed 4.5 since clients works on 4.0. However me as developer may work on 4.5 but I should set target framework to 4.0 in order not to get methods from 4.5 right?

Comment: @devhedgehog: Testers should get all possible SUPPORTED combinations of framework versions and Windows versions.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2013 you can still build against .NET 4.0. The (highest) framework version installed on your development machine has no influence on the end result of your build process.

When installing .NET 4.5 in place of .NET 4 will change something on your PC: It gives you the ability to compile against the 4.5 version of the framework. As long as your compile your code against the NET 4.0 version, it has no need of .NET 4.5 to be installed.

Comment: I think the OP is concerned about the fact that .NET 4.5 is an in-place upgrade of .NET 4.0.

Comment: I am asking this because I read that 4.5 replaces 4.0. Its not a side by side version thingy. So are you sure that when I pick 4.0 I ll get things 4.0 has?

Comment: If you read about @JohnSaunders's answer you know there are potential issues.

Comment: @LexLi: You are right. The OP just asked about the code compatibility. John pointed out the risks correctly.